# How can I plot a complex alpha in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

I'm new at QC, and one of the Qiskit quick exercises asks me to plot this ($j$ is the imaginary unit):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} j\\1\end{bmatrix}$, so I deduced $\alpha=j$ and beta= 1.

I know this is the equation:
$|q\rangle = \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} |0\rangle + e^{j\phi}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} |1\rangle$

I don't know how to plot it, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I did miss a lot of details in my question, I've already plotted 1, 2, 3, and 4 from the quick exercise. I just don't have a clue how to convert #5 to spherical coordinates in order to plot it.

[image: Quick Exercises]

Comment: can you provide the exercises link, or explain more what you want to visualize, there is a lot of visualize method, you can take at look here https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/visualization.html#counts-and-state-visualizations

Comment: I just edit my answer

Comment: accept the answer will help a lot thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can learn to look at Qiskit documentation, and figuring out how to solve the exercises by yourself.
https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/visualization.html

This is the way how I do the 5

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
initi_ = np.array([0.+1j, 1+0.j])/np.sqrt(2)
display(array_to_latex(initi_))
qc.initialize(initi_,0)
state = Statevector.from_instruction(qc)
plot_bloch_multivector(state)
```

[image]
[image]
so I know it is:

```
plot_bloch_vector([1,np.pi/2,np.pi*3/2], title="New Bloch Sphere", coord_type = 'spherical')
```